# Webpages are ending with .php/ and I can't figure out how to fix it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule to hide .php , but it's not working for .php/

Normally I wouldn't be concerned, but users are landing on pages on my site and seeing this so I'd like to hide it. Setting up a 301 redirect didn't work.

htaccess has:

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: _"Setting up a 301 redirect didn't work"_ - why not? Allow for an optional slash at the end (instead of at the front, where that is superfluous - when configured in .htaccess, the URL the rule matches the expression against never starts with a slash, that has been stripped off at that point already.)

Comment: No idea why not.. I haven't seen this issue before. I have the following in my htaccess but it doesn't redirect:  `Redirect 301 /sample-page https://www.example.com/sample-page.php/`

Comment: What, you _want_ users to see `https://www.example.com/sample-page.php/` in their browser address bar? I thought hiding the .php suffix was the intention?